# PHP script breaking rest of HTML document

Tags: php, html, simple-html-dom

**EDIT: SOLVED - Thanks to the comment by @Adam**

I have my index.php page, which all included functionality, until now, has worked.
I've written a small script (pasted below), using the Simple HTML DOM library to scrape an external webpage for an element value. This value is stored as $newprice inside the script. 
However, when I place the script anywhere in the code, it a) doesn't run, and b) breaks all HTML/PHP/JS code preceding it.

```
<?php
  include_once('../simple_html_dom.php');
  $html = file_get_html('https://www.affordrentacar.co.uk/');
  $traverse = $html->find('span.offer-price', 0);
  $newprice = $traverse->plaintext;
?>
```

I've copied this script to one of my other PHP pages and tested echoing out the $newprice variable and that works fine. What could be causing this?

Comment: What does your error log say? Also, are you sure the Simple Dom library is where you're including it from?

Comment: What is the error generated by the code. The term "doesn't run" is quite hard to debug. I am guessing that you can find some error logs on the server.

Comment: @Adam Well then, I guess this is one of those times where I let something stupid slip past me... the simple dom path was off by 1 directory! All fixed, cheers :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP's white screen of death](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1475297/phps-white-screen-of-death)

Answer (score 2):

try to display errors :

```
error_reporting( E_ALL^E_NOTICE );
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

can be problem with connections, your local settings don't work with https